# C# ListBox bug in ColumnWidth

Tags: c#

When i use listbox in c# (vs 2010 without SP1 Beta) with this setting:

```
MultiColumn = true
```

and

```
RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
```

and

```
ColumnWidth = 78 // 1 to 78
```

c# ignore

```
RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
```

and show from left side. like `RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No`

but when i use

```
ColumnWidth = 79 // 0 or greater than 78
```

that show correct.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I see any difference between 78 and 79.  Your code is hard to interpret, RightToLeft is not a boolean property.  It does look iffy, the 2nd column doesn't seem to be properly aligned.  Not sure, you didn't mention your Windows version either.

Solve you problem by drawing the listbox content yourself.  Use the DrawItem event, there's a good example in the MSDN Library article for it.

Comment: I use DrawItem, but that problem is still,

Comment: when ColumnWidth is equal 1 to 78, e.Bounds.X = 155 (e.Index = 0) but when ColumnWidth is equal 0 or greater than 78, e.Bounds.X = 233 (e.Index = 0)

Comment: i think e.Bounds.X must be same alwase.

Comment: Don't use ColumnWidth anymore either, you don't need it.  Make the columns in your DrawItem code.  Other than that, it sounds like you found out why it doesn't work properly.